# can ldap search query be continued from last value if disconnected in middle of search

Tags: ldap

is there a way to continue ldap search from left off point. Say my initial query was "*",ou=abc,dc=myldap,dc=net and it returns 490 rows then gets cut off (connection, server, etc..) can I continue from last value in ldap search query/filter or do ldap search filters only work on wildcards or high abstract queries

Answer (score 1):

No. LDAP is a "stateless" protocol. There is no method to resume a closed connection. Seems like you should explore why  your connection was "cut off".